# Query for non-partioned tables

Tags: postgresql, psql, database-partitioning

Using Postgres, is there a way to list tables, but not tables that are partitions of other tables?

```
\dt
```

lists all tables. I have thousands of tables that aren't "primary" but are just partitions of parent tables.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a missing feature in PostgreSQL, and you have to resort to the catalogs to get that information:

```
SELECT relname,
       relnamespace::regnamespace::name AS schema
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class
WHERE relkind IN ('r', 'p')  /* table or partitioned table */
  AND relpartbound IS NULL   /* exclude table partitions */;
```

Comment: I'd say it's a missing feature in `psql` not "PostgreSQL" ;)

Comment: Well, the PostgreSQL community considers `psql` a part of PostgreSQL, since it is a core component (different from pgAdmin).